# syncing mdadm event count

Tags: mdadm, raid5

I had a disk die in my level 5 RAID and before I could replace it, my RAID crapped out while I was copying some data onto it.

Reading [the RAID kernel wiki on RAID recovery](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery) I've tried forcing an assemble with no success:

```
# mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: /dev/md1 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.
```

The results from `mdadm --examine` are:

```
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2f3274a9:e3975c44:43e0066f:3c4e819d
           Name : Jupiter:1
  Creation Time : Sun Aug 26 17:41:46 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3907025072 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 3907023872 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6c242f92:9b39c56a:c238964e:82ed1fdd

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Sep 21 11:20:47 2013
       Checksum : e38c9e3b - correct
         Events : 13880

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)

/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x3
     Array UUID : 2f3274a9:e3975c44:43e0066f:3c4e819d
           Name : Jupiter:1
  Creation Time : Sun Aug 26 17:41:46 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3907025072 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 3907023872 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 395033224 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0aa93873:826723b0:5e73d226:dd8a8071

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug  5 05:11:05 2013
       Checksum : 8ddf93da - correct
         Events : 13298

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

My initial thoughts from reading the [wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery) is that is because the Event count is so different mdadm can't reassemble the array.

I'm confused because I've been copying data over to the array successfully until now, so I don't know why the Event count would have drifted so far apart.

I desperately don't want to lose the data, but I need to obviously get the RAID going to then add a new third disk.

Comment: `mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc1` you need a `missing` in there somewhere.  Also, order matters.